# CentOS 7 PV images?

Tags: centos, centos7, xen

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 under Xen as a PV DomU, but I can't find the needed `initrd.img` and `vmlinuz` images. Is there anywhere that I can download them, or if I need to, how can I generate them?

**Note:** I tried the pxeboot vmlinuz and initrd, but I got a kernel panic. The CentOS 5 Xen vmlinuz and initrd work fine. Perhaps it is possible to install 7 from the 5 install images?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 7 is HVM-only.

Comment: Oh, that's annoying. Any idea why they chose to do that?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure. It could be that PV is a pain to support and PVHVM performs better anyway, so why bother?

Comment: Ah. Could you by any chance point me to a tutorial on setting it up as PVHVM? I'm quite new to Xen.

Answer (score 0):

PVHVM is supported by default in Centos 7, see by using `grep XEN /boot/config-$(uname -r)` command

Also, PV is not supported, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50245_01/E63729/html/vmrns-bugs-vm-ol7-rhel7-pv.html

So if you want highest performance with paravirtualized storage and network, you should create host with CentOS 7 preset and install Xentools after that.